# capistrano or equivalent for wordpress, iis and mysql

Tags: php, iis, capistrano

I'm looking for a capistrano or equivalent solution to delpoy a wordpress/buddypress site on IIS and MySQL database server. Anyone, ever do this using capistrano or something else?

There is a similar question on here, but its for .net and sql server.

I would rather not use cygwin, so if that rules out capistrano all together. I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [phing](http://phing.info) (Phing is not GNU make)?

It's basically a project build/deployment solution based on Ant. It's platform independent and doesn't have any dependencies. I've used it in PHP projects and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano is something that runs on your local environment, not the server. Once you configure it, it can be set up to deploy to multiple other environments. Just because your web server is iis, doesn't mean you can't install Rails and Capistrano on your local dev (Rails comes pre-shipped with Mac OSX) and get it to work with your environment.